# How to implement Solr auto suggester and spell checker simultaneously on a single search box

Tags: solr, ofbiz

I am using Solr version 6.3 and have tried the following:

1. Used **FuzzyLookupFactory** as lookupImpl in the auto suggester but it gives me StackOverflow error.
2. **Spell Checking**: Does not provide suggestions when the correct keyword is typed.

Comment: So what does your queries look like? What is the Stack Overflow caused by?

Comment: This is my query:
 /suggest&df=productName&suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest.q=ca

But I need to perform context filtering which FuzzyLookupFactory doesn't support.